# Add validation to dynamic form

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a simple form that has multiple question and drop down as answers.

So here is my attempt.

I have successfully created a dynamic form. data get loaded properly to drop down answer but validation is throwing problem.

here is my form code

```
<div [formGroup]="formQ">
<div *ngFor="let question of questionList; index as i;" class="row">
    <div class="input-group col-md-12" style="padding: .15em .5em">  
        <div class="input-group-prepend col-md-9" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">                
            <label class="input-group-text w-15">{{i + 1}}</label>
            <label class="input-group-text w-100" style="text-align: left; white-space: normal;">{{question.quetext}}</label>
        </div>
        <select class="form-control" style="height:auto !important;" 
        [formControlName]="question.controlName"
         [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submittedQ && fQ.controlName.errors }">
            <option [ngValue]="null"> --Select-- </option>
            <option *ngFor="let ansItem of question.answerList" [ngValue]="ansItem" >{{ansItem.anstext}}</option>
        </select>
        <div *ngIf="submittedQ && fQ.controlName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="fQ.controlName.errors.required">Required</div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

```
export class formComponent implements OnInit {
  formQ: FormGroup;
  group: any = [];
  quesList: Question[] = [];
  submittedQ: boolean;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    private formService: FormService,
    public dialogService: DialogService ) {
      this.quesList.forEach(q => {
        this.group[q.controlName] = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
      });
      this.formQ = new FormGroup(this.group);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.submittedQ = false;
    this.formService.GetPageLoadData().subscribe(
      data => {
        data.forEach(q => {
          this.group[q.controlName] = new FormControl(q.selectedAns , Validators.required);
        });
        this.formQ = new FormGroup(this.group);
        this.formdetail = data;
    });
  }
  get fQ() { return this.formQ.controls; }

  submitForm() {
    this.submittedQ = true;
    if (this.formQ.invalid) {
      return;
    }
  }
}

export class Question {
    controlName: string;
    queid: string;
    quetext: string;
    isAtRisk: boolean;
    answerList: Answers[];
    selectedAns: any;
}
```

to identify control name I am padding names as ans_1, ans_2 and so on
The problem is fq.controlName.errors does not get resolved as fq.ans_1.errors and i am getting error

```
FormComponent.html:153 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controlName' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (FormComponent.html:155)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:30043)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:29439)
at callViewAction (core.js:29680)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:29643)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:29440)
at callViewAction (core.js:29680)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:29622)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:29445)
at callViewAction (core.js:29680)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated
find the app here 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-reuwfy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Thanks

Comment: Your app in the stackblitz does not have any error except missing `ReactiveFormsModule`. You have to import this in your app module to make reactive form work.

Comment: sorry I was working on it. I have updated the fstackblitz again. basically i have list of question and answer drop down options and selected answer in db. all i am trying to do is make a dynamic form that shows the list of question and answers and the selected answer  from db. Also user can change answer and if not answered validation should kick in

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot read property 'controlName' of undefined` it means you are trying to access `controlName` on an undefined variable. In your case `fq.controlName`. `fq` is `undefined` here.
Your function is `get fQ() { return this.formQ.controls; }`
Replace `fq` by `fQ`
`Q` is in capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ngOnInit you are using

`this.group[q.controlName] = new FormControl(q.selectedAns , Validators.required);`

then your controlname here would be `ans_1` not `controlName`

So in your template you should use like below:

Instead of `fQ.controlName.errors.required` use `fQ.ans_1.errors.required`

Here is the updated stackblitz for your reference [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4f7ufc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: I am trying to build a dynamic form. you solution will work if I have one question what if i have 10 or 100.. controlName should be resolved as ans_1 or ans_100 depending on the question that is not answered